# Given the solution of $Ax = b$, do we know whether $A$ spans $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $3 \times 4$ matrix such that all solutions to the equation $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ may be written as:

$$
\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{matrix} \right] + x_3 \left[ \begin{matrix} 3 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right]  $$

with $x_3 \in \mathbb{R}$. Does $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^3$, or can't we tell?

Comment: From context $A$ is a $4 \times 3$ matrix? Is $b$ anything in particular? If $b = 0$ then $A$ could just be all zeroes.

Comment: @Mummy_the_turkey: I'm assuming that what OP has written implies that the above covers *all* solutions of $Ax = b$. If $A$ were all zeroes, the set of solutions would have more elements.

Comment: Sorr @Mummy_the_turkey I should've specified that, the question says that A is 3 x 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "does $A$ span $\Bbb R^3$", you mean whether the columns of $A$ span $\Bbb R^3$, that is, whether the image of (the linear transformation induced by) $A$ is $\Bbb R^3$.
(And that $A$ is a $3 \times 4$ matrix.)

---

Recall the following:

If $x_0$ is a particular solution to the system $Ax = b$, then the complete set of solutions is given by $$x_0 + \cal N(A),$$
where $\cal N(A)$ denotes the null space of $A$.

---

In this case, we see that $\cal N (A)$ is spanned by one-vector, that is, it is one dimensional.

Recalling the rank-nullity theorem, we see that $$\operatorname{rank} A = 4 - \operatorname{nullity} A = 3.$$

Since the image of $A$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$, we see that $\operatorname{rank} A = 3$ gives us that $A$ does span $\Bbb R^3$.